# Filtering TOC using ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

[image]

[image]

I am very new to ArcGIS JavaScript and have been reading some samples from the API.

I am using ArcGIS JavaScript 3.5 API and agsjs.dijit.TOC control to display several layers in a map. I am trying to do the following:

Add a textbox, Type a layer name to filter, and the expected result is that only the filter layers should show up in TOC and the filtered layers in a map.  Like I said, I am using the TOC widget.

After looking around and reading a bit, I have been able to get a filtered array which has the list of filtered layers, but how do I update/filter the TOC contents with this?

```
var filteredArray = 
        array.filter(this.map.getLayer(this.map.layerIds[1]).layerInfos, function (item)
        {

            return item.name.indexOf("Text entered for filter") != -1;
        });
```

Comment: Can you post additional code?  If is difficult to make a suggestion with what is currently provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the latest version of the [API (3.8)](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jstutorials/#step2) before you do anything.

If you have not used [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) before, then this is the Javascript framework which the API is built upon.  There are many good form examples here which you can use in the TOC.  I would recommend the [Combo Box](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/ComboBox.html#dijit-form-combobox).  This seems to have the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: @jeremythamm- Thanks for your reply. I am also looking at dojo. I have updated my post with some screenshots. Screen shot 1 shows TOC of all layers, below is a textbox where some text to filter layer names can be typed. Once I typed the text 'base', it lists only the layers matching the search text. I hope this makes it a bit clear. As for the code, I only have the TOC widget code and another filter textbox, upon entering some search text, I am trying to update TOC.

Comment: I am still unsure of exactly what the end goal is?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I apologize, once a search text is typed in the filter, only those layers should show up in TOC. 'Filter by layer name' is the textbox where the user would enter some text. May be I am not being clear to you due to my lack of knowledge on this. For instance, in the second screenshot I typed 'base' as the text, TOC updated to show only the layer names that contained that text.

Comment: It sounds like then you have already accomplished what you are wanting to do.  If you type "base" in the text box and it does filter, it sounds like it is working correctly

Comment: This is just a sample from a different website I got. I am trying to implement this feature in the webapp I am developing. So far I can get the TOC to work, add a textbox to filter and upon changing/adding some text to the textbox, I am calling a function. But I am stuck there. From there on, I do not know how to replace the existing TOC with the filtered layers.

Comment: Ahh ok, why do you use their code since they have a working example?

Comment: I do not have access to their source code and the other website is done in Silverlight (I am not familiar with Silverlight).

Comment: Ok, here is a sample of a Javascript widget you could customize to meet your needs. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/map_multiplelayerdef.html  You can add the Dijit (combo box) and used this logic to filter layers

Comment: If you are not familiar with Javascript I would recommend Codecademy http://www.codecademy.com they have excellent tutorials

Answer (score -1):

Use the ctrl + f function and you can just tick the boxes on or off.

Comment: The question though asks about how to do this in JavaScript.